# Java: Writing content to file gets over written after all lines are written

Tags: java, filewriter, file-writing

I am trying to write text content into a file using Java.

I am using a loop that wraps the following code:

Note: `urlForAllStores` is a String object.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(Play.getFile(SHOPS_FILE),true); 
//the true will append the new data

    fw.write(urlForAllStores+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    //appends the string to the file
    fw.close();
```

It works fine, but then when my loop finishes all the content is deleted, and I lose all the results.

Is there anything in here that suggests that would happen, or is it likely to be in some other part of the code.

Comment: Why do you open a new writer _each time_ you enter the loop? Why don't you open it before the loop?

Comment: Good question @fge, that's an oversight on my part

Comment: You would have your answer by debugging the code, adding a breakpoint after the loop, look at the file while stuck in the breakpoint, and then resuming. The problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: OK, maybe this will not solve your problem but try and `flush()` before you `close()`. Also, if you use Java 7, use a try-with-resources statement

Comment: For my information, what is the difference between `System.getProperty("line.separator")` and `"\n"` ?

Comment: @fge Writer.close() flushes the stream before closing so that won't solve anything... this is peculiar though

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I will look at other aspects of the code. It may be something completely unrelated. Thanks again.

Comment: @Charlie I believe System.getProperty("line.separator") will get you the correct line ending for the operating system.

Comment: @fge using Java 6 - but will keep testing to find the problem

Comment: OK, do your stuff; however, you should specify the charset to use when opening the file, at this moment you don't do it.

Comment: When I moved the FileWriter constructor outside the loop, it writes the first line to the file, and then no more ... strange.

Comment: It's definitely a case of the bug being elsewhere, because now the original version is working with a smaller number of inputs. I wonder if there is a limit to how big a file I can create on my server, and it is being delete for being too big .... or something silly like that.

Answer (score 2):

I have a file at /home/charlie/file.txt, containing Hey

```
$ cat /home/charlie/file.txt
```

gives

```
Hey
```

After running this code

```
    try {
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(new File("/home/charlie/file.txt"), true);
        fw.write("This is written by Java \n");
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

(Because I don't have the class `Play`, you should give that in your post)

And this command

```
$ cat /home/charlie/file.txt
```

My new output is

```
Hey
This is written by Java
```

So I can't reproduce your problem to find what's wrong.

Please let me know whether it works or not
Happy coding :) -Charlie